# call a method in uitableivewcontroller from a method in custom uitableviewcell in the uitableivewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to call a method say

`-(void)calculateValues`

in uitableviewController from a custom- uitableviewcell method such as

`-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

.
The purpose is to refresh the values in other tableview cells  based on the value entered through a textfield in this uitableivewcell. but how to access the uitableviewcontroller from the cell;self.superview will only point to the uitableview but i need to get the viewcontroller.how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either a notification if its a few levels separated or a delegate pattern if you  know about the view controller at creation time of the cell.

Comment: Use NSNotification for just that, not method calls.  Notifications should have words in them like will and did.  Notifications should be used when the method receiving is not known to the notification sender .  SO if a notification is used name it something like CallerClasNameCellEditingDidEnd.